# Why is random.choice removing rows that it shouldn't?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset called 'gen' that has a column for 'churn?' with binary values - either 1 or 0. These are currently set to being integers.

The breakdown of value_counts() for the 'churn?' column is 1125 rows with a value of 0, and 154 rows with a value of 1

I would like to randomly remove ~200 rows with a value of '0' for so that the dataset is more balanced.

I have used the following code to do this:

```
# filter the dataset based on the specific values in the 'value' column

    rows_to_remove = np.random.choice(gen[gen['churn?']==0].index, size=200, replace=False)
                     
# remove the selected rows from the original dataset
    gen_new = gen.drop(rows_to_remove)
```

After doing this, I expected to have 925 rows with a value of 0, and 154 rows with a value of 1. However, I am only getting back 130 rows with a value of 1. For some reason 24, rows are being removed.

So it seems that the correct number of rows with value 0 are being removed, but for some reason some rows with value 1 are also being removed which shouldn't be the case.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your input and the matching expected output? Do you have unique indices in the index?

Comment: Too many unknown details for us to answer the question.  What is `gen`?  You said the column name is 'Churn', but the code uses 'churn?'.  Where, exactly, do those outcome variable come from?

Comment: In short, it's your job to provide a **complete** code that we can run ourselves, so we will get the exact same results.  Only then can we dig into the code to see the exact problem.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated above. In short: the dataset is called 'gen'; the column in question is called 'churn?'; 'churn?' can have one of two values, either 0 or 1; the gen dataset has 1125 rows where churn?==0, and 154 rows where churn?==1; I am trying to reduce the number of rows where churn?==0 by randomly deleting some; However, when trying to do this it seems that rows where churn?==1 also get deleted

Comment: tessema thanks for the additional details, please add them to the body of the question to signify their importance to new people reading the question

Comment: What is the output of `gen.index.duplicated().sum()`?

Comment: Apologies. I did try earlier for kept getting an error message. I have updated the body of the text above to make it clearer. And I have been successful using @mozway suggestion. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, you have duplicated indices.

Either reset your index (`gen = gen.reset_index(drop=True)`), then use your approach.

Or, use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
m = gen['churn?']==0

out = pd.concat([gen[~m], gen[m].sample(n=925)])
```